# Scroll to Fix - use Plagin

Tags: html, scroll, position, fixed, absolute

I'm trying to use this [code](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) in my project.
This is my [project](http://u2943455.mass.hc.ru/)

This is code of my js:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

 $(document).ready(function() {

// first two divs
        $('#side').scrollToFixed({
                marginTop: $('.zel_bg').outerHeight(true) + 55,
                limit: $('.indbag').offset().top - $('#side').outerHeight(true) - 20,
             });
        $('#esp').scrollToFixed({
                marginTop: $('.zel_bg').outerHeight(true) + 55,
                limit: $('.indbag').offset().top - $('#esp').outerHeight(true) - 20,
             });

// second two divs
        $('#ss1').scrollToFixed({
                marginTop: $('.zel_bg').outerHeight(true) + 55,
                limit: $('.oforbag').offset().top - $('#ss1').outerHeight(true) - 20,
             });
        $('#ss2').scrollToFixed({
                marginTop: $('.zel_bg').outerHeight(true) + 55,
                limit: $('.oforbag').offset().top - $('#ss2').outerHeight(true) - 20,
             });
 });         
    </script>
```

It's true when it calculate the place then make position: fixed for divs.
It's true when it calculate the place to make divs position: absolute.
But the place of divs is wrong in the last (bottom) part.

At first view, it seems like they just dissapear.
But code calculate the wrong height to place block in bottom part.

The code of plagin is wrong? Or how can i fix it?
Height of my page is fluid, and i cant give it as fix nubmer of pixels.
I thought, that this plagin "ScrollToFixed" will help me.
But i have problems that I told you earlier.

Comment: Please add more details..

Comment: I added more details.
I just use the complete javascript without any changes, and got wrong result